# multiple functions in ng-click only fire on function once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

I created a function which combine two other functions (recorder.start() and recorder.stop()) which can fire separately. When I tried to add these functions in one ng-click, the program only could fire one function at one time. If the program would like fire the second functions, I had to press the button again.Is it possible to fire two functions after press the button once?

JavaScript

```
$scope.record = function() {
        recorder.start($scope.recordConfig).then(function() {
            var test = $scope.recordConfig.captureSource;
        recorder.stop();
        })
    },

n.start = function(e) { 
        return t.postMessage("start", e)
    }, 

n.stop = function() {
        t.postMessage("stop")
    }, 

c.postMessage = function(e, t) { 
            return c.getPort().then(function(n) { 
                return n.postMessage({
                    type: e, 
                    data: t
                })
            })
        },
```

HTML

```
<md-button ng-click="record()" class="md-primary md-raised">Start Recording</md-button>
```

=======================================================================

- Further question:
  In this stage, I tried to use the below code in popup.html.js to control the two functions in one action. But I found the popup window will be closed when user change to another tab of chrome. As https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/faq#faq-dev-05 explained, "popups automatically close when the user focuses on some portion of the browser outside of the popup." Do you know any manner to keep the popup window always open? or let the stop() can run when the popup window is closed.

popup.html.js

```
    $scope.recordStart = function() {
       // recorder is an angular module which can postMessage such as start/stop/pause... ...

       recorder.start($scope.recordConfig)
        .then(function() {
            var test =  $scope.recordConfig.captureSource;
            "tab" !== test && "desktop" !== test || a.IS_E2E;
        })     


$scope.stop = function() {
        recorder.stop();
    }, 

$scope.record = function() {
      $scope.recordStart();
        $timeout(function(){$scope.stop(); },4000)
 }
```

Comment: you can add multi function in your ngClick by separator them with ";", but in this sample you need to detect start function timeout, it's right?

Comment: you're not executing them synchronously. `stop` will only be called if returned promise from `start` is successful. Are you sure it is? If yo don't want this just call `stop` from outside the `then`-success function. Also what is `"tab" !== test && "desktop" !== test || a.IS_E2E;`? it doesn't seem to do anything, right?

Comment: @Maher Thank you. I have had try add ";" in HTML but it's not work in this case. May I ask how to detect timeout?

Comment: @Gustav Thanks. I removed "tab..." In addition, I tried to put stop() outside then(function()) but it also showed the same symptom. I still had to press the button again to fire stop().

Comment: Your problem doesn't make much sense... Of course  `start()` and `stop()` will be called if you put them inside a  function to be executed by a ng-click. How is it that you determine they are not called? I think it is your logic inside the functions that are wrong, making you think they are not executed correctly. If you would put console.logs inside both `start` and `stop` you would see both be executed (also assuming you put `stop` outside the `then`)

Comment: @Gustav, sorry for making you confused. I would like to make the symptom clearly. I tracked the process and also saw start() and stop() were called during executed the  program. However, the recorder did not stop after press the button at the first time, even though the program had call stop(). When I pressed the button again, the program also called start() and stop() again, and I saw the recorder was stopped. I would like to know that why press the same button and call two same functions at a time but showed difference behavior?

Comment: Ok, then I think I need more of your code. It's hard to follow in the extra code you provided. It doesn't look like this is the exact code, right? where is `c`, `n` and `recorder` declared. What type of objects are they? is `n.start` the `recorder.start`-function? more descriptive names would make the code easier to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This sample show to you how can call two functions with one click using $timeOut
>
> In "CallFun" we used $timeout manually, calling "fun2()" after 2 sec.
>
> You can do that with calling API too.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", [])

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, $timeout){
  $scope.fun1 = function(){
    $scope.message = "Return function 1"
  }
  
  
  $scope.fun2 = function(){
    $scope.message = "Return function 2"
  }
  
  ///this is manually timeout
  $scope.callFun = function(){
    $scope.fun1();
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.fun2();
    }, 2000);
  }  
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    
    <button ng-click="callFun()">call functions with $timeout</button>
    
    {{message}}
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for solving the previous problem. May I ask you a further question about the behavior of func2? The html in my program which is like a popup window in chrome, but when I would like to switch to another web page, the html will be closed, and the func1 is still run in the background. However, the func2 will not be fired anymore. Do you know any manner to fix this problem?

Comment: Hi, please ask your question with sample, i can answer you better. tnx

Comment: I added more detail in the question area. If it's not clear enough, please let me know. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For functions the second parameter is your call back which you have applied but if you check it carefully you will find you are also injecting the third parameter and considering it to work as a callback. You can easily do this by calling one function inside other.

**eg.**

```
$scope.ParentFunction=function(){

   $scope.child_sibling1();

}

$scope.child_sibling1=function(){
    $scope.child_sibling2();
}
$scope.child_sibling2=function(){
  //your code
}
```